# factorization of even degree polynomial

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

i am interested in general  criteria about even degree polynomial factorization,maybe  number theories rule or some other   mathematical properties can be helpful,i am talking rules how to factorize  even degree polynomials or in other word if it is  possible given polynomial with degree $(2,4,6,8,...2*n)$ could be factorized.of course zero degree polynomial

$p(x)=a_0$

can be always factorized with  two product  of constants,also pay attention that my question  should satisfy   following criteria :polynomial with degree $2*k$   should be factorized as product of two polynomial with degree $k$,let say

$a*x^2+b*x+c$

degree here is $2$,so each   member   in product should have degree $2/2=1$ or

we should solve following equation

$(k*x+m)(d*x+e)=a*x^2+b*x+c$

we may solve this if we  enter some  values of $a,b,c$,but what is relationship between coefficients of small degree polynomial and  high one so that there should be quarantine  of being solvable? thanks in advance

Comment: Since you mentioned number theory I assume you are asking for factorization within the rational field. In general one has the Eisenstein criterion. It works surprisingly well. The algorithm implemented in maple, mathematica, etc may be also worth looking. I believe they do some sort of search algorithm over all smaller degree integer coefficient polynomials and perform long division into the polynomial.

Comment: but if we consider  in general,introducing irrational  or even complex terms?thanks  for reply

Comment: Check the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, the version of Carl Friedrich Gauß from 1799 hat your intended factorization as its title, every polynomial with real coefficients can be factored into linear and quadratic factors with real coefficients.